# Eclipse style auto close bracket in IntelliJ Idea (java)

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, ide, code-completion

As I slowly migrate to intellij from eclipse, I'm running into a few issues that are so microscopic in scale that they don't appear to have been asked before on the entire internet! Wild, I know!  This one relates to auto-closing of parentheses in intellij.

In eclipse, when you invoke a method, it autogenerates the open/close brackets, and you tab through the parameters until you're done.  Great! Just like intelliJ.  The difference is, in eclipse, to jump from inside the brackets of the method invocation to outside, I just type ')' and the IDE understands that it has already closed the bracket for me and so it moves the cursor to the end of the line and I add my semi-colon and away I go.

I cannot seem to find the equivalent behaviour in intellij.  I have asked a few of my idea-using colleagues at work what they do and they say they use either the END key to jump out of the method invocation or they use right arrow to get to the end of the line (depends on if they're on a laptop or not and if the END key is available.

For me, on a laptop it's fn + ->).  I find this extremely annoying.  Does anyone know how to get the eclipse behaviour or the special sauce (key) to jump out of the method? Enter, tab and space all do not do it.

Comment: Update: It appears there is a "jump out" checkbox under smart keys and the key would be "tab", but there appears to be a bug with our shops code formatter.  Our formatter adds a space after/before parentheses for readability. E.g. merger.merge( theParam ).  This might be why tab is not working with the "jump" checkbox enabled.